# CKQueryOperation error: This operation has been rate limited

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckquery

Client received `error 1298: This operation has been rate limited` error from CloudKit when downloading records with `CKQueryOperation`, only once, during Apple review. How can I fix this issue?

Here is to code, nothing special:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Movie", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", d!))
let qo = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
let fb: (CKRecord!) -> () = {record in

    temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({

        let fr = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movie")
        fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordName = %@", record.recordID.recordName)

        let a = temporaryContext.executeFetchRequest(fr, error: nil) as! [Movie]
        if a.count == 0 {

            let m = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Movie", inManagedObjectContext: temporaryContext) as! Movie
            m.title = record.valueForKey("title") as! String
            m.image = (record.valueForKey("image") as! CKAsset).fileURL.description
            m.imageSize = Int32(record.valueForKey("imageSize") as! Int)
            m.recordName = record.recordID.recordName
        }
    })
}

let c: ()->() = {

    temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({
        let success = temporaryContext.save(nil)
    })

    Utility.managedObjectContext().performBlockAndWait({

        let success = Utility.managedObjectContext().save(nil)
    })

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "moviesDownloaded")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema)
}

let cb: (CKQueryCursor!, NSError!) -> () = {cursor, error in

    if error == nil {

        if cursor != nil {

            let qo2 = Utility.qo(cursor, recordFetchedBlock: fb, completion: c)
            publicDatabase.addOperation(qo2)

        } else {

            c()
        }

    } else {
        Utility.log("error 1298: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.status.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        })

        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema)
    }
}

qo.recordFetchedBlock = fb
qo.queryCompletionBlock = cb
publicDatabase.addOperation(qo)

dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

I try to put this whole code into a loop like:

```
for i in 1 ... 2 {
var rateLimited = false

...
if error == nil {

} else {

    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3)
    rateLimited = true
}
...

if !rateLimited {

     break
}
}
```

Do you think it will work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you get `CKErrorRequestRateLimited` the error will have a `CKErrorRetryAfterKey` key in the error's `userInfo` dictionary. You should wait at least that amount of time before retrying your operation.

Waiting with a sleep is a bad idea because it can cause unexpected hangs in your application, especially if that code runs on your main thread. Use   `dispatch_after` or a `NSTimer` to re-send your operation.

Answer (score 3):

You will also get this error if you are not logged in to your iCloud account.